# What is the logical reasoning behind speed of light being the upper limit too given that it is constant, independent of relative motion?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Basically, using the two postulates of special relativity and other physical arguments, we can arrive at Lorentz transformation where gamma has to be real and thus we conclude any relative speed between two frames must be less than c (speed of light). I consider this to be rather mysterious as I had not expected this to happen after accepting the 2nd postulate.

I am still not convinced with the argument of deriving this major claim given that we already have one (2nd postulate); I feel there must be a logical way to deduce this (with no mathematics) which I can neither find anywhere nor think for myself.

So, what I am asking is the method to arrive at the conclusion using physical arguments, the 2 postulates and logic (no mathematical equations) only.

Comment: Sure, but I am asking if this fact can be deduced from other fact (2nd postulate). I mean if it were really an independent fact by itself (assuming one such fact of the constancy of speed of light already), it should have been listed as the 3rd postulate and not demonstrated as a consequence of those 2 postulates. Am I wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple argument that shows that the relative speed of two inertial frames cannot exceed the speed of light.

Suppose we have two observers A and B travelling at constant velocity, but whose relative speed is greater than the speed of light. A emits a photon towards B. In A's reference frame B is moving away faster than the photon, so the photon can never reach B.

But using the second postulate, the speed of light is constant in B's reference frame (so the speed of the photon is not affected by A's motion). So in B's reference frame the photon is approaching B at the speed of light and must eventually reach B.

By the first postulate the photon cannot reach B in one reference frame and can reach B in another reference frame. So our initial premise, that the relative speed of A and B is greater than the speed of light, must be incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

"given that it is constant, independent of relative motion"

It is not. The frequency and the speed of the light pulses VARY PROPORTIONALLY for the moving observer in Doppler https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg7O4rtlwEE, in violation of Einstein's relativity. The wavelength (or distance between subsequent pulses) obviously remains constant:

"Thus, the moving observer sees a wave possessing the same wavelength [...] but a different frequency [...] to that seen by the stationary observer." http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/315/Waveshtml/node41.html

Comment: From the page you linked, "An important proviso to the previous formula is that it is strictly classical, and only holds for non-relativistic motion (i.e., $ u_0$ , $ u_s\ll c$ , where $ c$ is the velocity of light in vacuum.) In fact, when applied to light propagation in a vacuum, the formula is only accurate up to first-order in $ u_0/c$ and $ u_s/c$."

Comment: The relativistic corrections (time dilation) do not change the fact that "the moving observer sees a wave possessing the same wavelength". Accordingly, the frequency and the speed of the light pulses VARY PROPORTIONALLY for the moving observer, with or without relativistic corrections.

Comment: Based on your answer here, you reject special and general relativity.  So why are you talking about time dilation and relativistic corrections?

Comment: "Based on your answer here, you reject special and general relativity. So why are you talking about time dilation and relativistic corrections?" For the sake of argument. That is, even if the relativistic corrections (that I do not accept) are taken into account, the speed of light remains variable.

Comment: The relativistic doppler effect is due to a combination of time dilation and length contraction.  The frequency changes one way and the wavelength changes in the other, with the result being that their product remains the same.  If you think mainstream physicists are so foolish as to overlook a middle school algebra error in the foundation of modern physics, I expect that no further discussion would be useful.